# How to use Delphi to execute a .bat file properly

Tags: delphi, batch-file

I am running a .bat file from delphi(2010).

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var sCmd: String;
 Begin
sCmd := Pwidechar('b4a_c2dm.bat' +' ' +'send ' + Trim(Edit1.Text)+' '  + Trim(edit2.Text ));
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'b4a_c2dm.bat', PChar(sCmd), nil, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
   end;
```

This opens the cmd.exe and passes the correct string in the cmd.exe , BUT

Some how the line in the .bat file (java -cp b4a_c2dm.jar anywheresoftware.b4a.c2dm.C2DM %*)  is showing up in the cmd.exe window and not letting the .bat file do its job.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Just a quick idea... not sure of the result... have you tried with a *start* or *call* as the _filename_, and the bat at the beginning of the parameters?

Comment: Tried it but it did not help.

Comment: the name of the bat file is b4a_c2dm.bat

Comment: If i open a cmd.exe and run the command like this

Comment: b4a_c2dm.bat send name message

Comment: Why do you say the line in the batch file isn't letting the batch file do its job? How have you confirmed that java.exe isn't running? What's running instead? How can you interact with it?

Comment: This is the line of the bat file(java -cp b4a_c2dm.jar anywheresoftware.b4a.c2dm.C2DM %*) it sends this to a b4a_c2dm.jar

Comment: I was useing the pause break button to catch the cmd.exe and look at it.

Comment: Mabie I am going about this wronge. Is there a way to open the cmd.exe and pass the string to it ?

Comment: You can use `CreateProcess()` to run cmd.exe directly.

Comment: Thanks to your comment createProcess i found a way here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100840/createprocess-returns-immediately-but-only-if-the-started-process-is-hidden) to do this job thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to execute a batch file, the program to be called is 'cmd' and its parameter should be the name of the batch file.

Regarding your program,

```
ShellExecute (application.handle, 'open', 'cmd', PChar(sCmd), nil, SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. This is been a problem for me.

Comment: I am useing your code now. It opens the cmd.exe but no (sCmd) string is in there just the cmd showing.

Comment: Try adding '/c' to the beginning of your parameter string, ie sCmd := Pwidechar('/c b4a_c2dm.bat'....Also, if you are passing literals, you could do that in one string, '/c b4a_c2dm.bat send ' + ....

Comment: I was trying to run a batch script as well, and tried Newman's idea, but all I got up was a command shell with no commands run on it.

Comment: @MarkAurelius: What would be your command line if you ran the batch file from DOS? What are you passing to ShellExecute?